# Background color overflowing out of border radius - React native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

[image]

applied background color getting overflow out of the border on android

```
 <CardView
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: 0.25,
                    borderColor: colors.secondary400,
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    ...shadows.shadowDefault,
                    shadowOffset: item.shadowOffset,
                    shadowColor: item.shadowColor,
                    shadowOpacity: item.shadowOpacity,
                    shadowOpacity: 0.32,
                    shadowRadius: spacing.SCALE_05,
                    shadowColor: Colors.black,
                    overflow: "hidden",
                  }}
                >
```

Comment: There's a border radius in your screenshot, but not in your styles. Where is that coming from?

Comment: its comming form CardView component, but when i add border width to 1 instead of 0.25 than background is not overflowing

Comment: Post all relevant code please

Comment: i found document where they have  mention min value of border width is https://infinitbility.com/how-to-create-a-border-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase border-radius to 0.5 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding resize mode : 'contain' to your cardView style

Answer (score 0):

This is because of border-width
Please remove border-width from this or provide in px it will fix your issue

Comment: but we want border to being displayed